# SharePoint 2019 x WebDAV

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, webdav

Good afternoon, is WebDAV still working on SharePoint 2019? Because when I clicked **Open with Explorer** it is trying to use OneDrive instead of the UNC path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDAV still working on SharePoint 2019.for your issue, check the following infomation:

SharePoint Open with Explorer uses ActiveX technology, so it's only supported in Internet Explorer.

Make sure The SharePoint add-ons are installed  and enabled.

[image]

Make sure windows WebClient service is running.

Open in Explorer or View with File Explorer in SharePoint for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/open-in-explorer-or-view-with-file-explorer-in-sharepoint-66b574bb-08b4-46b6-a6a0-435fd98194cc

Answer (score 4):

Yes, however it should be avoided whenever possible as it is significantly slower and there are some feature-related issues, generally around metadata and Document Sets, if in use.

Using the Modern interface will only open the OneDrive sync client -- the classic interface, when using Internet Explorer 11, should open Windows Explorer. But with that being said, there are various client and server configuration issues that can prevent Windows Explorer integration (or rather, WebDAV), from working properly.